# Rails - give users integer arrays - minimize api calls

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on a rails site that needs to store information from an API about the users. Is it possible to give users (a model) an array? If so, how do I do this?

I was looking through the documentation and didn't see it in the attribute types available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use serialize which allows you to save any ruby object into a mysql database.

For example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :my_array, Array
end
```

You can read the documentation [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods/serialize).

Comment: Thanks, How would I add this to an existing model? Serialize isn't a column and thus will need to be treated differently

Comment: You will have to make a migration to migrate the column data into a ruby array and then add the serialize commnad to the User model